# Issue with Join results in more than 2^31 rows

Tags: r, data.table

I have two huge data frames:

```
 > dim(res)
[1] 111478253         8
> dim(asign)
[1] 107371528         5
```

I want to merge them by "chr" and "pos"

```
> head(res)
    chr   pos a1 a2  a3         variant_id pval_nominal           gene_id
1: chr1 54490  G  A b38 chr1_54490_G_A_b38     0.608495 ENSG00000227232.5
2: chr1 58814  G  A b38 chr1_58814_G_A_b38     0.295211 ENSG00000227232.5
3: chr1 60351  A  G b38 chr1_60351_A_G_b38     0.439788 ENSG00000227232.5
4: chr1 61920  G  A b38 chr1_61920_G_A_b38     0.319528 ENSG00000227232.5
5: chr1 63671  G  A b38 chr1_63671_G_A_b38     0.237739 ENSG00000227232.5
6: chr1 64931  G  A b38 chr1_64931_G_A_b38     0.276679 ENSG00000227232.5
> head(asign)
          gene  chr                chr_pos   pos p.val.Retina
1: ENSG00000227232 chr1           1:10177:A:AC 10177     0.381708
2: ENSG00000227232 chr1 rs145072688:10352:T:TA 10352     0.959523
3: ENSG00000227232 chr1            1:11008:C:G 11008     0.218132
4: ENSG00000227232 chr1            1:11012:C:G 11012     0.218132
5: ENSG00000227232 chr1            1:13110:G:A 13110     0.998262
6: ENSG00000227232 chr1  rs201725126:13116:T:G 13116     0.438572

> m=merge(res, asign, by = c("chr", "pos"))
Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin ||    !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in more than 2^31 rows (internal vecseq reached   physical limit). Very likely misspecified join. Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and data.table issue tracker for advice.
```

I tried using by=.EACHI but got the same error.

I the final merged file I only need to keep matching: "chr", "pos", "pval_nominal","p.val.Retina"

I only need rows in common between "res" and "asign" data frames.

I can remove columns which I don't need from both of those data frames and I got this:

```
> head(asignx)
   chr   pos     p.val.Retina
1: chr1 10177     0.381708
2: chr1 10352     0.959523
3: chr1 11008     0.218132
4: chr1 11012     0.218132
5: chr1 13110     0.998262
6: chr1 13116     0.438572
> head(l4x)
    chr   pos     pval_nominal
1: chr1 13550     0.375614
2: chr1 14671     0.474708
3: chr1 14677     0.699887
4: chr1 16841     0.127895
5: chr1 16856     0.627822
6: chr1 17005     0.802803
```

But again when I try to merge these:

```
> m=merge(l4x,asignx, by = c("chr", "pos"),all.x=FALSE,all.y=FALSE)
Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin ||   !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in more than 2^31 rows (internal vecseq reached physical    limit)
```

Comment: Could you try `m=merge(res, asign, by = c("chr", "pos"),all.x=FALSE,all.y=FALSE)`?

Comment: I tried that and the same error as above: Join results in more than 2^31 rows ....

Comment: Is it possible that in both your tables (chr,pos) is not unique?

Comment: for unique combination of chr and pos I have one unique p value. So my data frames can be reduced on just those 3 columns: chr,pos, p val. I updated my post to reflect that.

Comment: I see that you are using `data.table`, you could use the `data.table`way of joining `l4x[asignx, on=.(chr,pos), nomatch=0]`

Comment: can you please give me code on how to do that?

Comment: I just updated my comment, not sure about the `on`part, tell me if it works

Comment: what do you get if you do `dim(unique(asignx[,c("chr", "pos")])` and `dim(unique(14x[,c("chr", "pos")])`?

Comment: I tried this: m=l4x[asignx, on=.(chr,pos), nomatch=0]. Again the same error: Join results in more than 2^31 rows ....

Comment: Pretty sure you have duplicates somewhere, otherwise an inner join can't have more rows than the minimum number of rows between two dataframes joined

Comment: @AidanGawronski I get: 7807222 and 10005412

Comment: therefore you do not have one unique combination of chr and pos, in either table.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. What I can do about that and solve this issue?

Comment: If you are expecting each table to be unique on those columns, determine why they are not, fix it, then perform the join. If the data is correct, then I would recommend doing this in SQL.

Comment: yes that data is correct. I am not really familiar with SQL. Do you have any code you can share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that both of your dataframes are loaded into a database (you will have to setup a database like postgres or sql server), the sql equivalent of:

```
m=merge(res, asign, by = c("chr", "pos"))
```

Is

```
select *
into m_table
from res 
join asign
on res.chr = asign.chr
and res.pos = asign.pos
```

Then you will have a new table:

```
select *
from m_table;
```